# How do I join tables for a search query in Codeiginter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Hi I have the following function that search uses to find information:

```
    function get_search(){
        $property_location = $this->input->post('property_location');
        $property_bedroom = $this->input->post('property_bedroom');
        $property_bathroom = $this->input->post('property_bathroom');
        $property_status = $this->input->post('property_status');
        $property_type = $this->input->post('property_type');

        $this->db->like('property_location',$property_location);
        $this->db->like('property_beds',$property_bedroom);
        $this->db->like('property_bath',$property_bathroom);
        $this->db->like('property_state',$property_status);
        $this->db->like('property_type',$property_type);
        $query = $this->db->get('property');
        error_log($this->db->last_query());
    return $query->result();
}
```

How would I join another table say property_images to the search so that data is included in the result?

Here is my view:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="page-header">
    <h4>Your search returned the following result(s):</h4>
</div>
<?php foreach ($results as $item): ?>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img
                    src="<?php echo base_url() . 'data/images/property_images/' . $item->image_name; ?>"
                    class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h4 style="margin-top: 0;">
                <a href="/property/view/<?php echo $item->property_slug;?>"><?php echo $item->property_name; ?></a>
            </h4>
            <p><?php echo $item->property_description;?></p>
            <p>Location: <?php echo $item->property_location ?> | Price: R<?php echo $item->property_price ?></p>
        </div>
</div>
    <hr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join in your query:

```
     function get_search(){
        $property_location = $this->input->post('property_location');
        $property_bedroom = $this->input->post('property_bedroom');
        $property_bathroom = $this->input->post('property_bathroom');
        $property_status = $this->input->post('property_status');
        $property_type = $this->input->post('property_type');

        $this->db->like('property_location',$property_location);
        $this->db->like('property_beds',$property_bedroom);
        $this->db->like('property_bath',$property_bathroom);
        $this->db->like('property_state',$property_status);
        $this->db->like('property_type',$property_type);
        $this->db->join('property_images','property.property_image_id=property_images.property_image_id');   //add this line in your code
        $query = $this->db->get('property');
        error_log($this->db->last_query());
    return $query->result();
}
```

Hope it will help you....

Comment: I get it to pull the images after the table has been joined but now it echo's out all the images I just need one per property how would I achieve this? here is the site just click on search with the default values and you will see what I mean http://hollowayproperties.co.za

Comment: ok you want to display only one image per property ? right ? and right now it is coming all images so the record is displaying 3 times or 4 depends on no of images.

Comment: hmm interesting now it only returns one record and not all the results so I assume I need to pass a $id variable somewhere?

Comment: ohhkei so remove that line i mean which line you added $this->db->limit(1); and add left in your join line: $this->db->join('property_images','property.property_image_id=property_images.property_image_id','left');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93994/discussion-between-riaanv-and-deep-parekh).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `join()` method of active records class you are using.

```
join($table, $cond[, $type = ''[, $escape = NULL]])
    Parameters: 

        $table (string) – Table name to join
        $cond (string) – The JOIN ON condition
        $type (string) – The JOIN type
        $escape (bool) – Whether to escape values and identifiers

    Returns:    

    CI_DB_query_builder instance (method chaining)
    Return type:    

    CI_DB_query_builder

    Adds a JOIN clause to a query.
```

[Reference](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::join)

In your example:

```
$this->db->like('property_location',$property_location);
$this->db->like('property_beds',$property_bedroom);
$this->db->like('property_bath',$property_bathroom);
$this->db->like('property_state',$property_status);
$this->db->like('property_type',$property_type);
$this->db->like('property_images.imageField', $imageFieldValue); // Observe change here.
$query = $this->db->get('property');
$this->db->join('property_images','property.your_id_field = property_images.your_id_field'); // Observe change here.
```

Comment: Thanks quys appreciate the input

Comment: I get it to pull the images after the table has been joined but now it echo's out all the images I just need one per property how would I achieve this? here is the site just click on search with the default values and you will see what I mean http://hollowayproperties.co.za